# Calculating KL Divergance in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am rather new to this and can't say I have a complete understanding of the theoretical concepts behind this. I am trying to calculate the KL Divergance between several lists of points in Python. I am using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html to try and do this. The problem that I'm running into is that the value returned is the same for any 2 lists of numbers (its 1.3862943611198906). I have a feeling that I'm making some sort of theoretical mistake here but can't spot it.

```
values1 = [1.346112,1.337432,1.246655]
values2 = [1.033836,1.082015,1.117323]
metrics.mutual_info_score(values1,values2)
```

That is an example of what I'm running - just that I'm getting the same output for any 2 input. Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can find the same discussion (with an answer) at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9262/calculating-kl-divergence-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I believe your trouble is that `mutual_info_score` only works with labels for input, not real values. The examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mutual-info-score) only use integer input, and code using integers produces different values, e.g.:

```
values1 = [0,0,1]
values2 = [1,1,1]
mutual_info_score(values1,values2)
```

Prints `5.5511151231257827e-17`.

```
values1 = [0,0,1]
values2 = [1,1,0]
mutual_info_score(values1,values2)
```

Prints `0.63651416829481289`.